# how does xscale & yscale work in TiKZ?

Tags: tikz-pgf, bodegraph

I am trying to read the documentation for `bodegraph` package (it´s in french!), right away the third example uses a code to generate two grids for two plots. Heres the MWE and a picture:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usepackage{bodegraph}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[xscale=7/5]
\begin{scope}[yscale=3/80]
\UnitedB
\semilog{-1}{4}{-60}{20}
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}[yshift=-3cm,yscale=3/180]
\UniteDegre
\OrdBode{30}
\semilog{-1}{4}{-180}{0}
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: A grid for bode diagrams]

In my opinion they look very tiny but I can´t understand how `xscale=m/n` or `yscale=p/r` works. I would truly appreciate if someone explained me how to make them as width as `0.5\textwidth` or `\textwidth` and also make them have the same height.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`xscale` and `yscale` are both simply scaling factors.

While I haven't looked at the code, it looks like `bodegraph` has as default 1 unit between the major gridlines on the x-axis (each order of magnitude). And as your diagram covers five orders of magnitude, `xscale=7/5` will give a diagram that is 7 units wide, plus the width of the axis labels. The default unit vectors in TikZ are 1cm long, so 7 units is 7cm.

For y it looks like there is no scaling done initially, so without `yscale`, a diagram that ranges from -60 to 20 will be 80 units (80cm) high. Hence, `yscale=3/80` gives an axis that is 3cm high.

Both your diagrams have the same height, because the first one has a range of 80 and `yscale=3/80`, while the second has a range of 180 and `yscale=3/180`.

If you want to set the width relative to `\textwidth`, you can do something like the following. The `\pgfmathsetmacro` is not strictly necessary, you can put the entire calculation directly into `yscale`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{showframe}

\usepackage{bodegraph}
% use 0.85 to allow for axis labels
\pgfmathsetmacro{\textwidthScaleFactor}{0.85\textwidth*2.54/72.27}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
% diagram covers 5 orders of magnitude, so 1/5
\begin{tikzpicture}[xscale=1/5*\textwidthScaleFactor]
\begin{scope}[yscale=3/80]
\UnitedB
\semilog{-1}{4}{-60}{20}
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}[yshift=-3cm,yscale=3/180]
\UniteDegre
\OrdBode{30}
\semilog{-1}{4}{-180}{0}
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Just to see if I get this straight in the factor m/n, m is the width you want in centimeters and n the order of the axis in this case each one has a width of 1 cm? And in the TextwidthScaleFactor that you show 2.54 is one inch in centimeter but what does 72.27 stand for? Is that the standard textwidth in centimeters?

Comment: @PaulLara 1) Yes, if by "order" you mean the range of the axis. Put differently, if you have `\semilog{0}{5}{0}{10}` without any scaling, the axis box will be 5cm wide and 10cm hight. 2) `\textwidth` is given in points, and there are 72.27 pt per inch.