# Bode grid template with configurable axes limits

Tags: tikz-pgf, gnuplot, bodegraph

I am using the bodegraph package from https://ctan.org/pkg/bodegraph with the intention of producing a nice A4 paper providing a bode grid with specific limits for amplitude and phase.

With the hints of another quesiton on this site (referenced in the MWE) i achieved a page with which I am basically satisfied.

Problem is, I want to be able to batch generate a number of grid pages that habe different axes limits.

In the provided MWE I use an y axes from -80dB to +20dB for the magnitude plot. Thought It would be easy to procude another page with y axes ranging from -60dB to +40dB (same number of divisions, same size on the paper, just different endpoints of the axes).

Turns out, not so easy since it instead shifts the whole grid. Unfortunately I do not understand the exact behaviour of the code and most of the documentation of the package is in france language ...

```
% needs -shell-escape
% needs gnuplot installed for this to work.
% uses https://ctan.org/pkg/bodegraph
% alternatively use of https://github.com/rlkamalapurkar/bodegraph for asymptotic lines

\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[margin=0pt]{geometry}
\usepackage{bodegraph}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\pagestyle{empty} %no page numbering in footer

\begin{document}

% the scaling was taken from
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/410128/how-does-xscale-yscale-work-in-tikz
% The default unit vectors in TikZ are 1cm long, so 7 units is 7cm.
% bodegraph has as default 1 unit between the major gridlines on the x-axis (each order of magnitude).
% if diagram covers 5 orders of magnitude, ->1/5
\pgfmathsetmacro{\textwidthScaleFactor}{0.85\textwidth*2.54/72.27}

\vspace*{0.5cm} %keep some space for the label

\begin{tikzpicture}[
    gnuplot def/.append style={prefix={}},
    xscale=1/8*\textwidthScaleFactor,
]

%Mag
\begin{scope}[yscale=12/100]
\coordinate[label=center:\bf{Angular Frequency $\omega$}] (A) at (3,-88);
\coordinate[label=left:\bf{Magnitude in $\mathbf{\left[dB\right]}$}] (B) at (0,25);

\OrdBode{10} % y axis step
\semilog{-1}{7}{-80}{20} % {décade mini}{décade maxi}{ymini}{ymaxi}
\end{scope}

%Phase
\begin{scope}[yshift = -15.5cm, yscale=12/270]
\coordinate[label=left:\bf{Angular Frequency $\omega$}] (C) at (3.7,-88-110);
\coordinate[label=left:\bf{Phase in $\mathbf{\left[^{\circ}\right]}$}] (D) at (-0.5,105);
\OrdBode{15}
\semilog{-1}{7}{-180}{90}
\end{scope}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: When I run your MWE I get [this output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4oGKT.png) on one page. Looks good enough for me. What is shifted? But you're also using `{-180}{90}` so of course the *y* axis goes from `180` to `90`.

Comment: {-180}{90} ist for the phase, for the amplitude it is {-80}{20} in my MWE. And that is fine. But try to change {-80}{20} to {-60}{40} and everything will shift